# Is it possible to calculate fractional decimal expressions using equ?

Tags: assembly, nasm

Part of my program code looks like this:

```
section .data
    maxlines    equ     8
    dataSize    equ     (((1 + maxlines) / 2) * maxlines) + maxlines                            
                                        
section .bss
    output      resb    dataSize
```

I need to calculate the number of bytes to assign to dataSize based on the sum of the sequence of consecutive numbers (plus one byte per new line) for each row, so that, for example, having `maxlines equ 8`, `dataSize` will be equal to `44`. I have found the formula (see source), but unfortunately I do not take into account a possible dicimal value and therefore it would work only when `maxlines` is odd. I could calculate the value for each use and put it as a constant in `dataSize`, but I don't like it as a solution. Or I thought you would use:
`dataSize dd (expression)`
but it seems that this declaration needs only constant values. Or again, I could calculate the expression on its own, directly through registers, but I also don't like this.
So my question is exactly what I wrote in the title.

Comment: nasm uses integer arithmetic. Rearrange your formula so division occurs later. Note that either `maxlines` or `1 + maxlines` is going to be even so their product is going to be even hence can be divided. `((1 + maxlines) * maxlines) / 2 + maxlines` should work.

Comment: I think you want to do rounding in your equates, which NASM can do. As Jester mentioned NASM does not support fractional expressions.

Comment: #Jester It is definitely the solution that I like the most.